# I have a Canon EOS 600D and it cannot take pictures, but it can record videos

Tags: canon, troubleshooting

I have a Canon EOS 600D that I believe may be broken or some random setting may have been activated.

Oddly enough, I can take videos with the camera, but when I attempt to take a picture or use auto-focus (basically press the shutter button), nothing happens. However, when I press the video button, it records videos as per normal.

I've tried resetting the settings and no notable change happens. Is there something I'm missing? Or is my camera *actually* broken?

Edit:
[image: Back of Camera]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44241/discussion-on-question-by-aytimothy-i-have-a-canon-eos-600d-and-it-cannot-take-p).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a cable release this will be easy. If not, it's a bit trickier, but still possible.

## Cable Release Jack

On the side of your camera you should have a cable release. On more entry-level models, it should be a 2.5mm jack, like this one on my T5

[image: cable release jack]

## A Cable! My Kingdom for a Cable!

If you have older video out cables from some point-and-shoot cameras or some video accessories, you may find that they used a 2.5mm jack. At least that's where this one came from. The RCA side (or not) isn't terribly important - the size of the stereo plug on the other side *is*. I believe it's also important to have the three bands vs. two. It should fit into the cable release jack on the side of your camera.

[image: Not a cable release. But it will do!]

## Fooooccuuuus....

If you have RCA ends like mine, then do it this way. If you have another stereo jack on the other end you'll need a paper clip, a penny, or some other conductive material. You just need to short (i.e. connect) the right two bits. The cable release jack has 3 connections in it - ground, half-press, and full-press. In my case, I have 4 connection points on the RCA sides. Two posts, and two sheaths. That means I can connect post-A to post-B, post-A to sheath-B, sheath-A to post-B, and sheath-A to sheath-B.

One of these things should work for you. Maybe.

[image: Focus, Daniel-san!]

## Why This Might Work

If this works, you have something horked up with your shutter button. That seems unlikely to me, but if you have a cable around like this it's the easiest thing to check.

Answer (score 1):

## Remove The Batteries

It's *possible* that some setting got screwed up on your camera. I don't know how, but obviously your camera doesn't currently work. So what I would try, if nothing else seems to work, is removing the batteries. Obviously you know how to remove the main battery, but removing the backup battery is usually a bit trickier. I thought that instructions would be [found in the manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/7/0300008087/03/EOS_600D_Instruction_Manual_EN.pdf), but I couldn't find them. There are some instructions for [changing the backup battery](http://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/education/infobank/batteries/care_of_batteries.do), though I'm not sure if your specific model has instructions there. But hopefully it's a similar approach.

By removing the batteries it *should* reset everything back to the factory settings, so if there is some setting you accidentally horked up, hopefully this will fix it.

Comment: Or you could use the `Clear Settings->Clear All Camera Settings` menu option.

Comment: I'd probably still try removing the battery (if that doesn't work), just on the off chance that maybe there's something stuck in the firmware. I don't have an intimate knowledge of camera firmware, but that strikes me as a distinct possibility (though improbable).

Comment: Turns out that the 600D doesn't have a removable backup battery, but rather uses a soldered-in capacitor to maintain clock etc. settings when the battery is removed.

Comment: Ick. Well, I guess the OP could leave their camera switched on, with no battery present, for a couple of years or however long it takes the capacitor to drain ;)

Answer (score -1):

Most Canon cameras have a switch for video mode built as a rotating ring around the button where you start the video (where it says 'Start/Stop').

You need to rotate that back into 'picture mode'.
[image]

Comment: I'm not a Canon expert, but the image in the question does not seem to show any switch like this.

Comment: the image in the question was added _later_, as a clarification _after_ I posted this answer. Yes, the D600 does not have this switch.

Comment: However, the question has clearly stated 600D since the very first version.